# Inverter Circuit using IR2113, TLC555 and signal inverter IC

Tags: inverter, high-frequency

Input DC = 30V

operating frequency = 10kHz

problem =
When I am at the no-load condition at the output, only the oscilloscope is connected, I am receiving the proper output. But when I connect a load, which is a 10 Ohm resistor, the output voltage drops down to almost zero.

I really need a bit of professional advice here.

[image: schematic]

Comment: what is the duty cycle of the drive signal? what is the 30V power source?post the scope capture

Comment: Scope the MOSFET gates and see if you are getting appropriate Vgs to turn on the MOSFETs. Cannot say much without looking at some waveforms.

Comment: The connections around variable resistor R1 are unclear. When R1 is turned to its lowest value you're theoretically trying to make an infinitely high frequency. I would add a resistor in series with R1 to define a proper minimum value (for the resistor) so that the highest frequency is properly determined. Also I would use **all** inverters in the 4049 IC, 2 in series with output of 555 and then 2 x 2 in parallel to drive the IR2113 inputs. You didn't ground the **unused inputs** of the 4049, that's not recommended. **ALWAYS** connect unused CMOS inputs to ground or Vdd.

Answer (score 1):

The circuit you you got it from and you show us is for wireless power transmission that is for high frequency whenever you  not to it fits you.